# Open local file in browser from app (android 4.3)

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that must open a local file in browser. In android versions less than 4.3 it works perfectly but in versions equal or above 4.3 the app always crashes. I think the problem is in Intent.ACTION_VIEW, but I dont have sure.

The code that I wrote is showed below.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
browserIntent.setType("text/html");
browserIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

So the question is: how to open a local file in browser from app in android versions equal or above 4.3.

Comment: what error its showing in the logact?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `setClassName()`. You should not assume what browser apps are installed on the device. All it matters that you request that some user-chosen app handles the URI with the specified data type for you.

To be extra resilient, catch `ActivityNotFoundException` in case there's no activity to handle the intent (e.g. due to a restricted user profile).